Как сделать так чтобы отображалось сообщение и подчеркивание ошибки поля ввода?



const showInputError = (formElement, inputElement, errorMessage, inputError, errorClass) => {
const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`.${inputElement.id}-error`);
inputElement.classList.add(inputError);
errorElement.textContent = errorMessage;
errorElement.classList.add(errorClass);
};

const hideInputError = (formElement, inputElement, inputError, errorClass) => {
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`.${inputElement.id}-error`);
  inputElement.classList.remove(inputError);
  errorElement.textContent = "";
  errorElement.classList.remove(errorClass);
};

const isValid = (formElement, inputElement, inputError, errorClass) => {
if(!inputElement.validity.valid){
showInputError(formElement, inputElement, inputElement.validationMessage, inputError, errorClass);
} else {
  hideInputError(formElement, inputElement, inputError, errorClass);
}
}

const setEventListenersForm = (formElement, validationConfig, inputError, errorClass) => {
 const inputList = Array.from(formElement.querySelectorAll(validationConfig.inputSelector));
 inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
  inputElement.addEventListener("input", () => {
    isValid(formElement, inputElement, inputError, errorClass)
  })
 })
}


const enableValidation = (validationConfig) => {
  const formList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(validationConfig.formSelector));
  formList.forEach((formElement) => {
    setEventListenersForm(formElement, validationConfig)
  })
}


enableValidation({
  formSelector: '.popup__form',
  inputSelector: '.popup__input',
  inputErrorClass: 'popup__input_type_error',
  errorClassActive: 'popup__input-error_active',
});
.popup__input-error {
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12px;
color: #f00;
opacity: 0;

}

.popup__input-error_active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup__input_type_error {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
<div class="popup popup_type_edit popup_is-animated">
      <div class="popup__content">
        <button type="button" class="popup__close"></button>
        <h3 class="popup__title">Редактировать профиль</h3>
        <form class="popup__form" name="edit-profile" novalidate>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="popup__input popup__input_type_name" id="name-input" placeholder="Имя" required minlength="2" maxlength="40">
          <span class="popup__input-error name-input-error"></span>
          <input type="text" name="description" class="popup__input popup__input_type_description" id="text-input" placeholder="Занятие" required minlength="2" maxlength="200">
          <span class="popup__input-error text-input-error"></span>
          <button type="submit" class="button popup__button">Сохранить</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>




А в чём проблема проверять форму и если она не валидна, то присваивать класс это форме и подчёркивать и делать всё что угодно. Так же и тест можно добавить? В чём проблема то?

Попробую объяснить иначе, Код который я скинул это дз с курса. Моя задача сделать так чтобы при неверном вводе, например в поле ввода минимальное допустимое значение  2 символа  minlength="2" или поле полностью пустое должно появиться сообщение о ошибке типо "Заполните это поле" и подчеркивание. Так как по заданию сказано создать обьект в вызове функции enebleValidation и вытаскивать от туда нужный класс. И у меня возник ступор где я ошибаюсь, почему не передается селектор  popup__input_type_error и cелектор popup__input-error_active

И весь мой вопрос заключается в том как правильно передать чтобы отобразились эти два класса
